# How to get cleveref to explicitly list each reference rather than joining them?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref

I am using `cleveref`'s `\cref{label}` command with multiple arguments.
I want to ensure that it explicitly lists all three sections that I am referencing regardless of if they are in order or not.

At the moment they are referenced as "sections 1 to 3" with the 1 and 3 being hyperlinked. 
I need all three listed something like "sections 1, 2 and 3" with all digits hyperlinked so that the reader can click through directly to section 2.

I am using `hyperref` for the links (and I've put the `\usecommand{cleveref}` after the one for `hyperref`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you want this for all types of references, just add the `sort` or `nosort` option to `cleveref`. With the former, different types of cross references (e.g. sections and equations) will be sorted together and they will be sorted by number as well. With the latter the crossrefs are placed as in the `\cref` command.

### With `nosort`:

[image]

### With `sort`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[
%sort
nosort
]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{a}\label{1}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq1}
a=b
\end{equation}
\section{b}\label{2}
\section{c}\label{3}

\Cref{3,2,eq1,1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, this does exactly what I was after.

Comment: However, the code you present, seems to do what I want with the sort. I have the labels in order already but with the sort on, instead of listing sections 1, 2 and 3 like in your example with sort, it lists sections 1 to 3.

Comment: It seems like there's something more at work here, like a compress option somewhere?

Comment: @Dom There's a separate `sort&compress` option (which is the default). `sort` should do just sorting, not compressing. So you don't get the same output as me, with my example?

Comment: your example comes out the same, it's just I was unaware that the default was neither sort nor nosort. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you don't want this for all types of references, you can separate the cross-references in the list by one or more empty references, at the point at which you want to prevent compression.

`\cref{eq1,eq2,,eq3,eq4,eq5,,eq6,eq7,eq8}` will be typeset as:

[image]

Or using the example from the other answer:

[image: cleveref example with(out) compression]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{a}\label{1}
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
a=b
\end{equation}
\section{b}\label{2}
\section{c}\label{3}

This sentence references \cref{3,2,eq1,1} using default options.
But this one references \cref{3,2,,eq1,1} without compression.
\end{document}
```

An empty reference ensures that the preceding reference will appear
explicitly in the final, typeset cross-reference.

You can safely put an empty reference between cross-references that would never be compressed anyway; it will simply be ignored.

Source: chapter 5 of [`cleveref` documentation](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf).

Comment: This is a very handy trick for one off compression blocking, or even as your example shows only blocking certain combinations.